# DataFrame pandas where cell = empty, assign category not working, assigns it to everything

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
| Receipient account nr| Name      |Category|
| -------- ------------| --------- |--------|
| EE123123-------------|David------|gibberish|
| EE1231212------------|Mike-------|gibberish|
|----------------------|Maxima-----|gibberish|
|----------------------|Konsum-----|gibberish|
|----------------------|nikeaadidas|gibberish|
```

I'd like it to assign the Category on rows where "Receipient account nr" is not empty (contains IBAN number) to 'Transfer'

I use the following line to do so:

```
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Receipient account nr'] != '', 'Transfer', df['Category'])
```

However, when I run this line, it assigns all the categories to 'Transfer', so the table will look like this:

```
| Receipient account nr| Name      |Category|
| -------- ------------| --------- |--------|
| EE123123-------------|David------|Transfer|
| EE1231212------------|Mike-------|Transfer|
|----------------------|Maxima-----|Transfer|
|----------------------|Konsum-----|Transfer|
|----------------------|nikeaadidas|Transfer|
```

This is my preferred outcome:

```
| Receipient account nr| Name      |Category|
| -------- ------------| --------- |--------|
| EE123123-------------|David------|Transfer|
| EE1231212------------|Mike-------|Transfer|
|----------------------|Maxima-----|gibberish|
|----------------------|Konsum-----|gibberish|
|----------------------|nikeaadidas|gibberish|
```

Comment: It works for me. Will you please add the result of running `print(df.head().to_dict())` to the question?

Comment: Sadly canno't due in a fair amount of time, I completely overhauled my program in order to translate it to English and simplified the table into 3 columns only. When I remove all the other factors and leave only the Transfer command, it still will assign the "Transfer" category to all transactions.

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't need to be in English, I don't think, for me to help.

Comment: {'Kuupäev': {0: '2021-09-01', 2: '2021-09-01', 3: '2021-09-02', 4: '2021-09-02', 5: '2021-09-02'}, 'Receipient account nr': {0: 'EEE123123', 2: 'EE123123', 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}, 'Saaja/maksja nimi': {0: 'mikroinvmikroinv', 2: 'Mike', 3: 'VEELLAMBISEMLAMSKE', 4: 'LAMBIMAKSE', 5: 'LambineEEEEE MAKSE'}, 'Summa': {0: -0.58, 2: -5.0, 3: -15.18, 4: -2.99, 5: -17.8}, 'Kategooria': {0: 'Mikroinvesteeringud', 2: 'Transfer', 3: 'Transfer', 4: 'Transfer', 5: 'Transfer'}}

Comment: I translated the needed Column names, "VEELLAMBISEMLAMSKE", "LAMBIMAKSE", "LambineEEEEE Makse" should all be categorized as other with the last line, which uses ~ to assign category to "Other" if the "Category" column is not one of my other categorizes. But since Transfer gets assigned to everything at first, it won't change anything to "Other"

Comment: My hypothesis is that it reads empty string and nan differently, at thats where the error comes in. Nan != empty string in the case, however i tried to a certain setup where I tried to read that if != nan, then assign "Transfer", and it didn't  work properly. Also, why the first transaction gets assigned "Mikroinvesteeringud" is because of another clause I have, and that is completely right.